# How to manage VMs in Windows 2008 R2 Core server?

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows 2008 R2 Core server running Hyper-v, for some reason, I am not able to use the Hyper-V manager to connect this server remotely(RPC service unavailable error). I am still able to use remote desktop to connect to the Hyper-V server. Is there any command to stop and start a VM inside the server?

I know there's a Powershell Management Library for Hyper-v, but I prefer not use any 3rd party tool if Windows 2008 server can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hyper-V on Windows Server 2008 R2 does not have built-in support for PowerShell cmdlets (there is built-in support for Server 2012).  If you want to use PS, you'll need to install the PowerShell Management Library for Hyper-V from [Codeplex](http://pshyperv.codeplex.com/releases/view/62842).  Even though it is not an official Microsoft product, they do coordinate on its development and it is generally considered safe.

Using Hyper-V manager remotely may require you to perform some additional steps (depending on how your server is configured).  Are the server and management workstations domain joined?  Do you have firewalls enabled?

Comment: "RPC service is unavailable" is a generic network connectivity error, so +1 for firewall settings. I would also do a "winrm qc" because I think the hyper-v console uses winrm.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had tried the solutions I can find for RPC error: disable firewall, restart winmgmt, use hvremote script to check the problem. The only thing I haven't done is to reboot the server.